# Store values in struct to fetch it later

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, struct

I have got some values from api and those are added to a struct as follows..

```
 let theProduct1 = Product(name: name, id: id, theRate: rate, quantity: qty, sku: skuCode, prdCateg: prodCat, prodDescr: description, images: myproductImages, mrp: mrp)
```

Here `Product` is the struct. These are then added to an array `productData123` of type `[Product]` as below...

`self.productData123.append(theProduct1)`

Further, in  my `didSelectRow`, I'm assigning the images in my struct to another array in a different viewcontroller like so...

```
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "catalogueIdentifier") as! CatalogueViewController

let myprodObj = productData123[indexPath.row]

controller.productImages12 = myprodObj.images
```

But the issue is I want to store `productData123` in CoreData/UserDefaults so that I don't need to give an api call everytime & can fetch the required data from the database.

Comment: How do you jump from your own (struct) model to CoreData?

Comment: Actually..it was a suggestion..:) But I ultimately want to store my `productData123` somehow so that I can fetch it later...

Comment: If your goal is to save data to a file, you might want to create a model with Class as opposed to Struct.

Comment: But almost everything is implemented...and changing to Class at this point won't be practical...:( Can I not store my struct in any manner..?

Comment: Then run a search for struct and save.  Some people have shown how to save a struct model to disk.

Comment: Hmm...ok...would u mind suggesting how...? I'm a bit confused..:)

Comment: Core Data doesn't work with structs, only with instances of `NSManagedObject` or a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Data for this, but you might want to consider a more lightweight solution first. If you are using Swift 4 you have access to the Encodable/Decodable/Codable protocols for serializing objects.

Consider the following:

If you were to adopt the `Codable` protocol on your products class, you could then de/serialize your objects from your API to the file system (documents directory in the example). Since UIImage does not conform to the `Codable` protocol you would need to manually handle the decoding/encoding to another type (`Data` in the example below).

```swift
struct Product: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var rate: Double?
    var quantity: Int?
    var sku: String?
    var productCatalog: String?
    var productDescription: String?
    var images: [UIImage] = []
    var mrp: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case rate
        case quantity
        case sku
        case productCatalog
        case productDescription
        case images
        case mrp
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.rate = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .rate)
        self.quantity = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .quantity)
        self.sku = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sku)
        self.productCatalog = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productCatalog)
        self.productDescription = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .productDescription)
        self.mrp = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mrp)

        if let imageData = try container.decodeIfPresent([Data].self, forKey: .images) {
            imageData.forEach({ (data) in
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.images.append(image)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encodeIfPresent(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(rate, forKey: .rate)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(quantity, forKey: .quantity)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(sku, forKey: .sku)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(productCatalog, forKey: .productCatalog)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(productDescription, forKey: .productDescription)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(mrp, forKey: .mrp)

        var imageData = [Data]()
        for image in images {
            if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                imageData.append(data)
            }
        }

        try container.encode(imageData, forKey: .images)
    }
}
```

Than, you can use a JSON or PLIST encoder to read and write that data to disk:

```swift
struct ProductData {
    var products: [Product] = []

    var productsURL: URL {
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        guard let url = urls.first else {
            fatalError("Document Directory url invalid")
        }

        return url.appendingPathComponent("products.json")
    }

    mutating func loadProducts() {
        products.removeAll()

        guard let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: productsURL.path) else {
            return
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            products = try decoder.decode([Product].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
    }

    mutating func saveProducts() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()

        let data: Data
        do {
            data = try encoder.encode(products)
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
            return
        }

        do {
            try data.write(to: productsURL)
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

Additional information for encoding and decoding of custom types can be found here: [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)